# Text Corpus for finding important words in a news headline

Tags: machine-learning, nltk, corpus

I am working on a small project which requires me to find the keywords for a news headline. I simply used tfidf using nltk.webtext (http://www.nltk.org/book/ch02.html#web-and-chat-text) as the corpus and each sentence assumed to be as the document. The idea being idf would give me an idea of how important a word is.

The results would clearly depend largely on the underlying corpus. Webtext clearly is biased towards things on internet, thus they are tagged not-so-important by the algorithm.

1. What according to you will be a relevant corpus, and
2. What will be the corresponding document?

Headlines would be centred around politics, events, sports, etc. So, say a book by Charles Dickens would be pretty neutral, but is there more organized way to approach this?

Comment: Will this be helpful ? http://qwone.com/~jason/20Newsgroups/

Comment: Umm. Looks so. Still a question should be - shouldn't we target neutral datasets such as a book on fiction.